# ormlite duplicate id using gson and retrofit

Tags: android, ormlite

I am having issue on using `ormlite` it gave me duplicate id error, below are my pojo:

```
public class ParticipantDetailsModel {

@DatabaseField(id = true)
private int id;

@DatabaseField
private String first_name;

@DatabaseField
private String last_name;

}

public class Trainings {

@DatabaseField
private int id;

@DatabaseField
private int participant_id;

@DatabaseField
private int batch_id;

@DatabaseField
private int graduation_program_id;


@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, foreignAutoCreate = true)
private ParticipantDetailsModel participant;

}
```

Currently i need this `@DatabaseField private int participant_id` to populate data to local db. And i just need this one for joining purposes :

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, foreignAutoCreate = true)
private ParticipantDetailsModel participant;


[Ormlite Problem with duplicate field][1]
```

Here is my joining query:

```
 qb1.where().eq("id", item.getId()).and().in("participant_id", parId);
        List<Trainings> u = qb1.join(qb2).query();


SELECT `Trainings`.* FROM `Trainings` INNER JOIN `participantdetailsmodel` ON `Trainings`.`participants_id` = `participantdetailsmodel`.`id` WHERE (`Trainings`.`id` = 34 AND `Trainings`.`participant_id` IN () )
```

ON `Trainings`.`participants_id` = `participantdetailsmodel`.`id` this one return null because it is null on the local db.

Comment: Maybe try naming fields in database? @DatabaseField has name property...

Comment: @Max : When i renaming it, for instance private ParticipantDetailsModel participant; changing it to participants, of course duplicate name error will be gone, but when i try to use joining query it does not give me any values since it is null in the local db. please see attachment for additional info